# Помощь с preg_replace в php

Tags: php, preg_replace

Есть переменная с текстом:

```
$text = '143.50 рубль (без НДС)<br />Стоимость доступа к услугам контент-провайдера устанавливается Вашим оператором. Подробную информацию можно узнать в разделе «Услуги по коротким номерам» на сайте www.mts.ru <http://www.mts.ru> или обратившись в контактный центр по телефону 8 800 333 0890 (0890 для абонентов МТС)»';
```

Как вырезать всё то, что после `<br />` и `<br />` тоже?

Мой способ почему-то удаляет только `<br />`, а всё остальное не хочет:

```
$text_result = preg_replace('/<br \/>(.*?)/is', 'adsasd', $text_result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('/(.*)<br \/>.*/is', '$1', $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Так не проще?

```
$text_result = substr($text, 0, strpos($text,'<br />'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<br \/>.*
```